# Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.9.2-p180 and UTF-8 issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm having some trouble with UTF-8 characters. Here's db/seeds.rb

```
User.create(username: 'eml', first_name: '****', last_name: '****äck', 
            email: 'somemail@example.com', password: 'asdasd')
```

My terminal (OSX 10.5.8) is set to use UTF-8, Rails (according to application.rb) is set to use utf-8. Here's the error:

```
$ rake db:seed
rake aborted!
/Projects/***/db/seeds.rb:8: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/Projects/***/db/seeds.rb:8: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/Projects/***/db/seeds.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
...ame: '****', last_name: '****äck', 
...                               ^

Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line `# encoding: utf-8` on the top of `seeds.rb` file and any ruby file use spécials chars

I recommed you to adding `Encoding.default_external = "UTF-8"` to `config.ru` file and in `config/environment.rb` for encoding templating

And finally you can add `"".force_encoding('UTF-8)` to your string that pose problems.

Update :

Add full line on config.ru :

`# Not override -E option or LANG and apply only for ruby > 1.9

if Object.const_defined?(:Encoding) && !ENV['LANG'] && !ENV['RUBYOPT'].include?('-E')

  Encoding.default_internal = 'utf-8'

  Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8'

end`

[Source](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/483)

Comment: Nice, that did the trick. Hopefully it'll work for my AJAX-stuff too which is having troubles displaying characters correctly too. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah looks like I'm not out of trouble. All of a sudden my views are giving me nothing but errors. >_<

Comment: Don't forget add `encoding: utf8` for your database adapter too, in your database.yml

Comment: good call, turns out the problem with my views is related to Rails 3.1. Views named .coffee will incorrectly encode UTF-8 or something.