# Invalid multibyte char with Ruby 1.9, setting encoding: utf-8 does not fix it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I just upgraded my Ruby version from 1.8.7 to 1.9.2 (using RVM). So Ruby is: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]. The app is on Rails 3.2.8. Since upgrading, I get an error regarding multi-byte characters.

I've found multiple *very similar* issues on stackoverflow, but none of the solutions in them worked for me:

[Ruby 1.9 - invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678172/ruby-1-9-invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii)
and
[invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) with Rails and Ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739836/invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii-with-rails-and-ruby-1-9) 
and
[Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.9.2-p180 and UTF-8 issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774080/rails-3-1-ruby-1-9-2-p180-and-utf-8-issues)

When I start my app, and try to browse to it, I multiple errors, such as:

> SyntaxError
>   (/Users/antun/ror/parktwor3svn/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:35:
>   invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
>   /Users/antun/ror/parktwor3svn/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:35:
>   syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ']' ... States",
>   "Afghanistan", "?land Islands", "Albania", "Algeri...

The offending code (in app/helpers/application_helper.rb) looks like this. For brevity, I've boiled it down to just the first few countries - the "Å" in "Åland Islands" is one of the characters that triggers it. When I look up that character in my editor, I get: 00c5. (There's a bunch more unicode characters in other country names).

```
  def countries
    return ["", "United States", "Afghanistan", "Åland Islands", "Albania"]
  end
```

So far, I have tried adding the following to app/helpers/application_helper.rb *as the very first line* to fix it:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

and

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

and

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

None of these worked.

My config/application.rb has:

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

My text editor is VIM, and when I do :set encoding on that file, it returns: "encoding=utf-8".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tool such as *od* (assuming you're on Linux) to look at the *actual contents of the file*. If you have single byte C5, your file isn't in UTF-8. It's probably stored in ISO-8859-1 or similar, and Ruby is quite correctly complaining.

Comment: Thanks! That set me in the right direction. I'm on OSX, so I used the command "file -I app/helpers/application_helper.rb" to discover that it was in fact saved in charset=iso-8859-1. I then edited it in VIM again, and corrected that by calling :set fileencoding=utf-8. (It turns out that in VIM, calling :set encoding does not change the file's encoding; I found that out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1459612/1597106 ).